# Securely passing database updates to a server outside a vpn

Tags: php, sql-server, ftp, aes, vpn

I've spent quite some time now trying to figure out how to pass a few rows from a server inside a SonicWall VPN to a remote VPS cloud server. The server inside the VPN is Microsoft 2003 running SQL Server 2005, the destination server is a CentOS 6 with MySQL. I've been unable to find a way for the CentOS to easily and securely access the MSSql server from outside the VPN. I have extremely limited knowledge of SonicWall or other firewalls in general and I really don't want to open the door to security risks. So in light of this I've come up with the following solution:

1) A scheduled PHP script extracts the rows and encrypts them in AES-256 inside a password protected excel file

2) The script then uploads the excel file to my remote server using FTP

3) The remote server, having the same encryption keys, decrypts the file and uploads the rows to the MySQL database.

Two questions:

1) Is this a safe method of moving sensitive data from one server to another?

2) Is there an easier way to access the data that I have not thought of?

Comment: Have you considered a web service using ssl?

Comment: How about cURL + SSL?

Comment: Reading about it now... but it looks like I would have the Windows Server make a secure connection to my CentOS VPS using cURL and insert the new rows?

Answer (score 1):

You're involving FTP and files for what is essentially a system-to-system transfer which can result in trouble due to file locks and just looks ugly.

A better approach would be to have the remote CentOS box expose a port / web service that is exposed by HTTPS which requires client side authentication :

1. Your script retrieves the rows from some source
2. The script converts the rows to a form the server can read
3. The script calls the port exposed by the client, this is an outgoing connection so should be easier to get outside the VPN (based on the fact that getting an FTP connection outside the VPN is possible)
4. The script verifies the server side certificate and provides it's own client side certificate and transmits the rows over SSL
5. The CentOS host receives the rows and processes them as required.

With your current approach you will need to secure the FTP connection somehow, to do so securely will require both the service and client to authenticate themselves to one another and SSL does most of the heavy lifting in that regard in terms of connection negotiation and protocol flow.

Comment: Excellent, this got me reading. Do you think a Python SSH script periodically run on the Windows server would suit this?

The CentOS server has SSH and it looks like I can use Paraminko to make a Python script to execute SSH commands from Windows.

Comment: @Candide SSH would be a good alternative to SSL which would simplify key generation and key distribution to the remote server. You should be able to get all the Windows infrastructure you need to regularly running a script, I personally would use Cygwin